# Visual Studio multiple instances get swapped on windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ide

I always keep two instances of Visual Studio open. Occasionally the positions of the two instances get swapped on the task bar. I guess it is a bug, which has not fixed by Visual Studio team yet. Is there something that I can do in order to prevent that? This is really important to me as I need my old project on the left had side and the new project on the right hand side as I used to. I mainly code using C#, AngularJS and Java Script

VS version - 'Professional 2015'

OS Version – 'Windows 10 Pro'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the IDE window becomes [unresponsive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633526(v=vs.85).aspx) during some heavy operation (loading project?) and stops getting counted as a window (it gets replaced by a ghost window created by Windows) and when the real window starts responding again it is seen as a new window by the Taskbar and is placed last in its group. You can verify this by running [ProcDump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump) with the `-h` switch.

There is nothing you can do to prevent it. You could file a bug and hope it gets fixed.

If it is that important to you, you could create a little app that hides the "wrong" IDE window and then just shows it again, that should change the order. You could also try playing with [ITaskbarList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774652(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try your suggestions.

Comment: Anders wrote _"you could create a little app that hides the wrong IDE window and then just shows it again"_. **HideThatWindow** can do exacly this. After selecting left window just uncheckmark and checkmark "In taskbar".